# Shouldn't there be a puddle jumper in Egypt at the end of Moebius in Stargate SG-1?

Tags: time-travel, stargate, stargate-sg1, paradox

I've just rewatched *Moebius*, and made a realisation at the end of the episode regarding the puddle-jumper they use (the one discovered in *It's Good to be King*:

> The alternate SG-1 (along with the original Daniel) manage to stop Ra from taking the Egyptian stargate so it can be found again in our timeline. They also ensure that there is a tape explaining what happened and also put the ZPM where it can be found. So, doesn't this also mean that the puddle-jumper which they used could also be in the desert somewhere (in fact, that is how the alternate team actually get it because the original team left it there in the first place).

But, I don't remember the puddle-jumper being shown or even mentioned in the rest of the series - [GateWorld](https://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s8/819.shtml) hints the jumper is right where it started - but that doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: FWIW, we know puddle jumpers can last a while, as all the ones we've seen are thousands, if not millions, of years old.  Good question.

Comment: Simply. Yes... There should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The truth is, we don't know exactly what happened to the jumper. The facts are as follows.

1. There was a puddle jumper in the past.
2. This puddle jumper was not able to get the crew home, for whatever reason.
3. The crew survived enough to record a video, and had the ZPM.

I think it's reasonable to say that the puddle jumper was damaged quite seriously, but everything else played off without a hitch. It must not have been in good enough condition to save, or perhaps it was destroyed to keep other people from using it, who had seen it do things.

Comment: It could also just be buried deep in the desert sands and just hasn't been found yet.

Comment: @BBlake at the least it should have been found soon after the team returned, as they would have known right where it was. I think most likely either (A) the team destroyed it to keep anyone from finding it in the intervening years as Pearsonartphoto answered or (B) someone else found it (would've been a nice plot point for an episode) and the SGC covered it up

Comment: I don't know about that.  Landscapes change a great deal over thousands of years, especially in the desert.  They might have a general idea of where it is based on a relative position to a fixed landmark such as the pyramids, but everything else would have changed in the interim.  I would see it as more likely that they have a general idea of where it is, but can't justify the effort of coverup involved in a major archeological dig needed to find its exact location.